# Can git fsck be run while developers are accessing repository?

Tags: git

We want to periodically check the integrity of our (server-side) git repositories. Do we need to disable access to the repositories while running git fsck or can it be run while developers are accessing the repository, e.g. committing files?

Comment: `git fsck` does not attempt to fix anything, so at worst, if it does not lock against updates, you might see "corruption" that is not actually present.  Which might be a bit alarming but you can just run `git fsck` again to see if it was a one-off that should be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for garbage collection, nothing is ever deleted from the object db.  So, even if a ref is deleted while fsck is running the result is going to be correct for the situation as it was when fsck checked that ref's spot.  And if fsck sees garbage before gc deletes it, all that'll tell you is to run gc, which will hurt nothing.

It's telling that fsck doesn't do anything to show it's running.